# Subscribing to a hashmap updates using Kotlin Flows

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

Hi everyone I have been looking at this class

```
data class Message(val id: String, val text: String)
data class Conversation(val id: String, val messages: List<Message>)
class InMemoryDataSource {
    private val conversations: MutableMap<String, Conversation> = mutableMapOf()

    fun updateConversation(conversationID: String, newMessage: Message) {
        conversations[conversationID]?.let { currentConversation ->
            conversations[conversationID] = currentConversation.copy(
                messages = currentConversation.messages + newMessage
            )
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to update the implementation to be able to subscribe to updates on the conversations map as well as subscribe to updates for the individual conversations within the map, so I have updated the implementation to the following

```
class ObservableInMemoryDataSource {
    val conversationsFlow = MutableStateFlow<MutableMap<String, MutableStateFlow<Conversation>>>(mutableMapOf())

    fun updateConversation(conversationID: String, newMessage: Message) {
        conversationsFlow.update { conversationsMap ->
            conversationsMap[conversationID]?.update { conversation ->
                conversation.copy(
                    messages = conversation.messages + newMessage
                )
            } ?: run {
                conversationsMap[conversationID] =
                    MutableStateFlow(Conversation(id = conversationID, listOf(newMessage)))
            }
            conversationsMap
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a sample main function to run this implementation

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    runBlocking {
        val source = ObservableInMemoryDataSource()
        launch {
            source.conversationsFlow.collect {
                println("--------updates from the conversationsFlow--------")
                it.forEach {conversationFlow ->
                    println(conversationFlow.value.value)
                }

            }
        }
        source.updateConversation("1", Message("1", "hello"))
        delay(1000)
        launch {
            source.conversationsFlow.value["1"]?.collect{
                println("--------updates from the conversation[1]--------")
                println(it)
            }
        }
        source.updateConversation("1", Message("2", "one more"))
        println("should be updating")
    }
}
```

This implementation works as expected but I am worried about a few things

- The performance of this implementation having many nested flows into the map
- Deletions how to avoid memory leaks if the instance an individual flow is removed from the map
- concurrency issues do you think this code requires a mutex to be thread-safe

I appreciate all thoughts on considerations that would make this into a more robust solution

Edit #1
Here is an implementation that I think might satisfy most cases

```
class InMemoryDataSource {
    private val _conversations = MutableStateFlow<Map<String, Conversation>>(emptyMap())
    val conversations: Flow<Map<String, Conversation>> = _conversations.asStateFlow()
    private val mutex = Mutex()

    fun getConversation(conversationId: String): Flow<Conversation?> {
        return _conversations.asStateFlow().map { it[conversationId] }
    }

    suspend fun updateConversation(conversationID: String, newMessage: Message) = mutex.withLock {
        _conversations.update { state ->
            val result = state[conversationID]?.let { currentConversation ->
                state
                    .filterNot { it.key == conversationID }
                    .plus(
                        mapOf(
                            conversationID to currentConversation.copy(
                                messages = currentConversation.messages + newMessage
                            )
                        )
                    )
            } ?: run {
                state + mapOf(conversationID to Conversation(id = conversationID, listOf(newMessage)))
            }
            result
        }
    }

    fun removeConversation(conversationID: String) = mutex.withLock {
        _conversations.update {
            it.filterNot { it.key == conversationID }
        }
    }
}
```